# equivalence relation and quotient set, Given $A = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Given $A = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, **Write the appropriate equivalence relation of this quotient set:**
$$A/_R = \{\{1,2\},\{3\},\{4,0,5\}\}$$

Well, if it was to compute $$A/_R = \{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\}\}$$ I believe it would be simpler, something like:

$[0]_r = \{0\}$, $[1]_r = \{1\}$ , $[2]_r = \{2\}$ , $[3]_r = \{3\}$ , $[4]_r = \{4\}$, $[5]_r = \{5\}$

How do I compute if there is something like $\{1,2\}$? Thanks on advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the ordered pairs belonging to $R$ on base of:

$$R=\{\langle x,y\rangle\mid x,y\in\{1,2\}\vee x,y\in\{3\}\vee x,y\in\{4,0,5\}\}$$

That leads to something like:
$$R=\{\langle1,1\rangle,\langle1,2\rangle,\langle2,1\rangle,\langle2,2\rangle,\langle3,3\rangle,\dots\}$$

There will be $2^2+1^2+3^2=14$ pairs that belong to $R$.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: Are you sure that is the answer to the question? Because a friend told me that equivalence relation has to be written with $aRb$ whereas there need to be a condition inside paranthesis. something like, for the second example $aRb = mod6$

Comment: $aRb$ is a notation for $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$. It can happen that an equivalence relation $R$ is defined in a way as: $aRb\iff\cdots$ where $\cdots$ is some expression in $a$ and $b$. That however does not wipe away the fact that $R$ is - as a relation on $A$ - a subset of $A\times A$.